# addAll() method is not supported by RealmResults

Tags: java, android, realm, retrofit, deprecated

What can I use instead of addAll() method in my adapter, I'm using realm version 2.0.1 and that method is deprecated, I'm trying to get all the data from the API, save it to my database and pass it to my adapter, I'm using like this:

```
  public void getData(int page) {
    if (GlobalModel.existeConexao()) {

        Call<PedidosResponse> call = ((NavigationMain) getActivity()).apiService.getPedidos(GlobalModel.getToken(), GlobalModel.geEmpresaId(), page);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PedidosResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PedidosResponse> call, Response<PedidosResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getPedidos().size(); i++) {
                        Pedidos mPedido = response.body().getPedidos().get(i);
                        int myInt = (mPedido.isProjecao()) ? 1 : 0;
                        if (!mRepositorio.checkIfExists(mPedido.getId())) {
                            mRepositorio.addPedido(mPedido.getId(), mPedido.getCliente_id(), mPedido.getData_hora(), mPedido.getData_pedido_cliente(), mPedido.getPrevisao_entrega(), mPedido.getFrete_tipo(), myInt, mPedido.getObservacao(), mPedido.getAliquota_projecao(), mPedido.getStatus(), mPedido.getPedido_cliente());

                        }
                    }
                    arraypedidos = mRepositorio.findAllPedidos();

                    if (mPedidosAdapter == null) {
                        mPedidosAdapter = new PedidosAdapter(getActivity(), arraypedidos);
                        listpedidos.setAdapter(mPedidosAdapter);
                    } else {
                        mPedidosAdapter.setData(arraypedidos);
                    }


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PedidosResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                if (t.getMessage() != null) {
                    Log.v("pedidos", t.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Verifique sua conexão", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

But when I run the app I get this message:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This method is not supported by RealmResults.
```

Comment: is `pediosItens` object of `RealmResult` or `RealmList`?

Comment: @MohammedAtif pedidosItens is a RealmResults

Comment: I will prefer `List<Pedidos> pedidosItens = new ArrayList<>()` because `RealmResult` or `RealmList` is prefered when you are performing operations on Realm but for other operations its preferable to use `List`

Comment: And adding up to the point, `RealmResult` is used when you directly initialise it with `RealmQuery` in othercases you must use `RealmList`

Comment: `padidosItens` needs to be a `RealmList`. A `RealmResult` is immutable.

Comment: RealmResults are managed by the Realm. It's a list of pointers to objects that satisfy the conditions defined in the query. "adding" to it doesn't make any sense. Look into using https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters currently what you're trying to do doesn't really make sense, and I'd have to know what you're ACTUALLY trying to do to help.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I've updated the question

Comment: Ah. You're not actually using Realm's auto-updating feature, even though you seem to intend to use it. Please read this article:  https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149#.3uyz4fnjp primarily the section about auto-updating result set and `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `RealmResults` is just a set of pointers that satisfy the condition defined in the query. You can't manipulate it, nor should you if you just intend to show every element in your adapter.

In fact, [Realm was explicitly designed to simplify the workflow of "downloading data on a background thread and saving the data in a database", and "showing the data downloaded on a background thread automatically on the UI thread"](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149#.3uyz4fnjp).

This is what `RealmChangeListener` is for.

Simply put, all of this code is unnecessary:

```
                arraypedidos = mRepositorio.findAllPedidos();

                if (mPedidosAdapter == null) {
                    mPedidosAdapter = new PedidosAdapter(getActivity(), arraypedidos);
                    listpedidos.setAdapter(mPedidosAdapter);
                } else {
                    mPedidosAdapter.setData(arraypedidos);
                }
```

---

And could be replaced with this:

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    PedidosAdapter pedidosAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.some_view);
        pedidosAdapter = new PedidosAdapter(context, mRepositorio.findAllPedidos());
        // set adapter, ...
    }
}
```

And

```
public class PedidosAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Pedidos, PedidosViewHolder> {
    public PedidosAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<Pedidos> results) {
        super(context, results, true);
    }

    // onBindViewHolder

    // onCreateViewHolder
}
```

For this, use [RealmRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters), unless you intend to handle the `RealmChangeListener` manually.